# Visual Studio 2022 .NET 5+ API stops debugging on image upload

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Whenever I start my .NET 5 API in debug mode and I try to upload an image with my browser, not associated in any way with the .NET project, VS 2022 stops the debug process.

For instance if I use https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept and upload an image with the input field , the debug process stops.

It also stops whenever I:

- Try to log in using FB/Google login button anywhere
- Using Brave (browser) have two separate browser profiles open and close one of them

Any ideas on what it might be? Or a way to search out a cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution

**In Visual Studio 2022 you need to uncheck: Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects: "Stop debugger when browser window is closed".**

Apparently Visual studio treated every image upload or every browser that is closed as closing the debug browser window and stopping the process. Weird.

Comment: While disabling this option does correct the problem, it simply hides the bug in VS 2022. In my situation, the browser window is still open. Simply adding a panel to my SPA which instantiates the File Open dialog to open through Browse.. button will terminate the debugger. My guess is that, on Chrome at least, there's some sort of Spawn Process going on with the File Open dialog and once the dialog closes the signal is sent back to VS2022 debugger that 'A' browser instance ended. VS2022 then aborts the debugger abruptly. :(